# Refactoring code with DataSource and DataBinding

Tags: c#, data-binding, refactoring

I have this simple application that is checking for Employee Position , and then it returns html table(actually I've used repeater instead of html table) with information according to some business rule.Everything was easy , but then I had idea what if employee has 2 positions in company , and I need to return html table with information according to both positions.Now I have list of positions `listPositions` that maybe contains more then 1 position.My code(business logic) looked like this :

```
Dictionary<string, Action> actions = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
{
  {"Admin", new Action(() => 
           {rptEmployees.DataSource = spc.GetEmployeeInfo(Models.PhoneNumbers.AllEmployee);
            rptEmployees.DataBind();} ) },

  {"OfficeDirector", new Action(() => 
        {rptEmployees.DataSource = spc.GetEmployeeInfo(Models.PhoneNumbers.OfficeEmployee);
         rptEmployees.DataBind();})},

  {"RegularUser", new Action(() => 
            {rptEmployees.DataSource = spc.GetEmployeeInfo(Models.PhoneNumbers.OfficeDepartmentEmployee);
             rptEmployees.DataBind();})}

  };
```

My method `GetemployeeInfo()` is taking `SPListItemCollection` as parameter and returning EmployeeInfo objects which I bind to `rptEmployees` repeatar.

Rest of code(business logic) I thought should be like this :

```
foreach (var position in listPositions)
        {
            if (actions.ContainsKey(position))
            {
                actions[position]();
            }
        }
```

But  it's obvious bug, because when there is more than 1 position in the list, this part of code first binds `repeater` with informations for the first position and after second binding , these informations are lost.
Is there any posibility to refactor business logic and to get information for both positions without changing code in `Dictionary` segment ? Or should I try different approach?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution to my problem :) It was really simple one.
First, I've created  list `List<Models.EmployeeInfo> Employees`

Then simple modification of previous code:

```
 Dictionary<string, Action> actions = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
 {
   {"RegularUser", new Action(() => { Employees.AddRange(spc.GetEmployeeInfo(Models.PhoneNumbers.OfficeDepartmentEmployee));})},
   {"DeliveryManager", new Action(() => {Employees.AddRange(spc.GetEmployeeInfo(Models.PhoneNumbers.OfficeDepartmentEmployee));})},                
   {"OfficeDirector", new Action(() => {Employees.AddRange(spc.GetEmployeeInfo(Models.PhoneNumbers.OfficeEmployee));})},
   {"Admin", new Action(() => {Employees.AddRange(spc.GetEmployeeInfo(Models.PhoneNumbers.AllEmployee));})}

};

  foreach (var position in listPositions)
  {
      if (actions.ContainsKey(position))
      {
         actions[position]();
      }
  }

  rptEmployees.DataSource = Employees;
  rptEmployees.DataBind();
```